# Jboss Error While debugging -FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I am using `Ubuntu 15.04`, `java 1.7`and mysql 5.6. I am not using any server
I have a demo application where I am trying to fetch the data from db.
When i run the program from main method in the log I am getting null pointer exception.

To check when I am trying to debug as java application, I am getting an error message saying

```
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: No route to host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

1. What is the cause of this error?
2. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this message using folowing command:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=n,suspend=n
```

Changing to

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

solved the problem.